# Auto connect to any open WiFi with Debian

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, wicd

I have a WiFi module that is registered with a WiFi network.  There are a few other WiFi networks in the area.  The computer, however, does not know which WiFi network it can connect to.

So the computer has try to see which WiFi it can access the internet with.  If it can't get on (and say access cnn.com) with one WiFi, it should try the next.

Is there a way to automatically do this with debian or a program like WiCD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in BASH.
Simply check your connection every minute or ping response(if its too high).
Scan networks, and switch it.

for scanning you can use:
$ iwlist wlan0 scan

for connecting you can use

`#!/bin/bash

killall -9 dhclient

ifconfig wlan0 down

ifconfig wlan0 up

iwconfig wlan0 channel CHAN

iwconfig wlan0 essid ESSID

ifconfig wlan0 up

dhclient wlan0`

you can easily bind(combine) the scanning script to(with) the connecting one using grep/awk/cut which are very helpful tools.

If you are using Ubuntu(Spying!!!) turn off network-manager service by:
temp solution till reboot
$ /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
permament solution till chmod +x (when you want networkmanager back)
$ chmod -x /etc/init.d/network-manager

on Fedora(You are safe for now!) the service is called NetworkManager:
temp sol:
$ service NetworkManager stop
perm sol:
$ service NetworkManager disable